# Jquery ajax retrieving text (numbers) from php mysql

Tags: php, mysql, jquery

I've just started learning Jquery and I'm trying to post and retrieve some data with Ajax. The data that i wanna extrapolate is some simple text (no json), more specifically numbers. So I wrote this:

```
$.ajax({
    url : 'finproj.php',
        type : 'POST',
        data : 'p=' + devidproj,
        success : function(resultaat) {

var lengtebalxkx = Math.floor(100*resultaat/<?php echo $number; ?>);
$(".ongelezendonatiesproj").animate({opacity:1}, 300).show(); 
    if(lengtebalxkx > 120) 
        {
            $(".ongelezendonatiesproj").width(120);         
        }
    else 
        {
            if(lengtebalxkx < 1)
            {
                $(".ongelezendonatiesproj").width(2);       
            }
            else { 
            $(".ongelezendonatiesproj").width(lengtebalxkx - 10);
            } 
        }
         },
});
```

devidproj is a number, as is $number. I tried adding `dataType : 'text',`
But that didn't work.
The php-file which I'm trying to retrieve the data from, is:

```
<?php include('config.php');
$pid = $_REQUEST['p'];
$nieuwgeld = mysql_query('SELECT bedrag, aantal, projectid FROM donaties WHERE projectid="'.$pid.'"');
while($nieuwebed = mysql_fetch_assoc($nieuwgeld)) {
$plusbedrag = $nieuwebed['bedrag'] * $nieuwebed['aantal'];
$nieuwebedragen = $nieuwebedragen + $plusbedrag;
}

if($nieuwebedragen<>0) {echo $nieuwebedragen;} ?>
```

The php-file works fine.

I think I missed a comma or something in the Jquery-script but I can't seem to see what's wrong with it :s I've tried debugging it with alert() but that didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

use

```
data : {p:devidproj},
```

insted of

```
  data : 'p=' + devidproj,
```

Comment: for debug for error, remove all code in 
success : function(resultaat) { }
and simple put alert(resultaat) in this code. so you can predict where is you actual problem.

Answer (score 0):

Use the following data on your ajax request:

```
 data : {p: devidproj}
```

Note that there should be no quotes on `p`.

You should also parse the result on your Ajax request as integer thru `parseInt()` function since that's suppose to be a number. JS will parse it as string by default if not added.

```
 var lengtebalxkx = Math.floor(100*parseInt(resultaat)/<?php echo $number; ?>);
```

Comment: Yes, but it didn't find anything, I'm gonna rewrite the code differently and if i'm still having problems I'll get back to you. Thanks again for your help.